# Please scope your questions well, Is there something we could do to make this better?

Tags: discussion, scope

It is very easy to expand the scope of your question by too much. This is especially true on this site because the complexity of subjects is often high. As a result of this complexity we will easily suffer from the [bikeshedding effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality) where people talk and argue much of the easiest things.

It is best to keep this in mind and not overload your questions with too much things. For people who ask question this means:

- Supply context and some constraints
- Ask one thing at a time.

For those who answer

- Try to outline the scope of your answer when the question is too broad.

Stackexhange forums do not really always measure competency or best answer. But it is always at the same time kind of popularity contest. One should understand thins and not get too emotionally attached to down votes.

Is there something we can do to make scoping easier? Write about it in the about page?